# Rendering the same view/controller via a different route

Tags: ember.js

I have a view (and controller) in my application in which it makes more sense to set a "editingMode" boolean to true, in order to put it into edit mode.

While editing, I want to show a couple different modals (each with their our resource under the router). So I'm having a few issues in figuring out the right way to set this up.

```
/category        # "normal" view
/category/edit   # category view/controller with the "editMode" set to true
/category/edit/subcategory  # needs to show the categoryController with editMode set to true and then subcategory index above it.
```

So the router is setup like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){ 
  this.resource('category', function(){
    this.route('edit');
    this.resource('subcategory', function (){});
  });
});
```

Obviously, I can't make `subcategory` a nested resource under `edit`. So I figure my two options are.

## Option One

Put the main controller, handling all the function of `Category` under `CategoryIndexController`. But this requires two things.

1. The edit mode for category loads that view and controller (this is easy enough)
2. Each modal I want, has to first load the index view and then load itself into that view. This is annoying and doesn't seem as clean as option #2.

## Option Two

Put the main controller under `CategoryController`. This would mean:

1. The `CategoryIndexController` really does nothing.
2. The edit mode would still tell the `CategoryController` to set it's edit mode to true
3. Nothing has to happen with the modals (other than telling the `CategoryController` that it should be in edit mode.

This seems like the cleaner options to me, but I can't see to make it [work](http://jsbin.com/okanot/4/edit). Any ideas?

Is there a better way to do this or a more "correct" way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your `CategoryIndexController` instead of `CategoryController`. By default `CategoryController` will redirect to `CategoryIndexController` since that is a resource.